# Turned on my computer to find resolution all messed up, screen identified as "Generic Non PnP Screen"

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, resolution, external-display

I turned on my computer to find the resolution abnormally low (everything was big etc).

In the Device Manager, my screen was being identified as Generic Non-PnP Screen.

I have a Windows 8.1 desktop, and nothing changed overnight while the computer slept.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution turned out to be

- Right click in the desktop and select "Screen Resolution"
- Click "Detect"

Voila. Your screen should be detected and normalcy restored

(I suspect I moved my screen after putting computer to sleep, which may have jiggered the wire)